# How to find the time difference in milliseconds between an epoch timestamp and std::chrono::system_clock::now

Tags: c++, epoch, c++-chrono

Hi all I have created a c++ app  that among others it uses std::chrono in order to calculate  time differences.
At some point I upload a file to a server and as a response I get an epoch timestamp from a receive.php that informs about the timestamp when the file is fully uploaded to server. I'd like to calculate a time diff between this epoch time stamp and a starting point of my choice since I should not change this receive.php way of working.
So far I tried to achive this by using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
auto epoch1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() ;
auto epoch2= std::chrono::duration<long long>(epoch_time_stamp);
auto diff = epoch1 - epoch2 ;
auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(diff);
cout << s.count() << endl;
}
```

Where the epoch_time_stamp is a 13 digit epoch timestamp e.x 1501190040123.
However I get false results. I tried to pass epoch_time_stamp both as int64_t and time_t but with no success.Since I'm quite new at using std::chrono I assume that the cast  of epoch2 is not correct.

Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know, your `epoch_time_stamp` is a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  When you say:

```
auto epoch2= std::chrono::duration<long long>(epoch_time_stamp);
```

you are quietly converting that count of `milliseconds` into a count of `seconds`.  You can convert it to a count of `milliseconds` with:

```
auto epoch2= std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli>(epoch_time_stamp);
```

And then I think you will start getting results that look right to you.

I find it helpful to create a templated using alias like this:

```
template <class D>
using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, D>;
```

Now `sys_time<milliseconds>` is a `time_point` which counts `milliseconds` since the epoch.  This would allow you to simplify your code down to:

```
auto remote_time = sys_time<milliseconds>{milliseconds{epoch_time_stamp}};
cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now() - remote_time).count() << "ms\n";
```

For more details about `<chrono>`, please see this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M).

Answer (score 0):

The complicated answer:

```cpp
auto epoch2 = decltype(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())( epoch_time_stamp );
```

The easier answer:

```cpp
auto epoch2 = std::chrono::milliseconds( epoch_time_stamp );
```

So You suspected correctly. Missing in the declaration of duration is the ratio (otherwise known as *unit*). In this case it should be std::milli; And `using milliseconds = duration<long long, milli>;` which gives the easier answer.

The complicated answer is determinig the type which is returned by `std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()` and then invoking the constructor of the type with the epoch timestamp.